# Verify if city is in a country through google api working only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api

I have used the following code to verify if a city is present in a country, upon city change.  The city is entered in an input and I have an onchange event on the input.  The country is selected from a dropdown.
Below is the code:

```
$("body").on("change", ".geo-city", function (e) {
var city = event.target.value;
var country = document.getElementById("countryId");

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();


geocoder.geocode({
        'address': city
    componentRestrictions: {
        country: country,
    }
}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length > 0) {
    alert("ok")
    } else 
    alert("ko");
});

});
```

This code works only the first time the city is changed. However the 2nd time the city is changed,  both values city and country are sent to the jQuery but when it does the checking through geocoder instance, the values are set to undefined.

Any idea of how to correct check if the city is in a given country?  What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: @Taplar : I have editted the code to a working one.  Can you help now?

Comment: Ok, now the first thing that I notice is that you are passing in the event as `e`, but then trying to use `event`, which is an issue.